# Error "This element has no attached source and the Javadoc could not be found in the attached Javadoc."

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, javadoc

In Eclipse plugin development, I'm importing packages via the `MANIFEST.MF` file. So I don't have a lib folder and no referenced libraries section.
I can't see the javadoc comments even for the most basic methods like `String.format()`
The warning I get is:
"This element has no attached source and the Javadoc could not be found in the attached Javadoc."
Also when I click on "Open Attached Javadoc In A Browser", I get a security warning which asks me if I really want to visit the webpage. If I confirm, I can see the javadoc in the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have selected a Java Runtime which doesn't contain sources. Check the preferences "Installed JREs" and make sure they include sources.

Comment: Yeah you're right, there is no source attachment for the jars.
However there is a valid javadoc location URI:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/

Comment: Use a Java runtime which contains `src.jar`. If it already has one, then delete the runtime and create it again from scratch. Eclipse should notice the source JAR and attach it properly (you'll see little overlays over the JAR icons when this happens).

Comment: Thanks that worked. Apparently jre doesn't contain that src file. I downloaded the jdk and used the src file in that.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the source code for referenced libraries. Go to Plug-in Dependencies, choose the jar you want and hit Ctrl+Enter (Properties) and add the path. For most libraries you can download a jar containing the source.
[image]

Comment: I checked now. The external plugins is not the problem. What I can't see is the javadocs for basic classes like String or Integer. I think they are part of the jre but the URL doesn't work somehow.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/